# Ignoring target dir in sub projects

Tags: git

I've project structure like so :

```
/parentproject/.gitignore
/parentproject/subproject1/target
/parentproject/subproject2/target
/parentproject/subproject3/target
```

To ignore the target folder in each dir is this correct :

.gitignore contents :

```
/*/target
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/*/target` will match the directory structure you specified.

If you want to ignore *every* target directory deeper in your directory structure you can use the line `/**/target`.

This will ignore:

```
/parentproject/subproject1/target
/parentproject/subproject1/subproject2/target
/parentproject/subproject1/subproject2/subproject3/target
etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your .gitignore `/**/target`